# Eclipse: How to restore template proposal description for JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Ever since Oracle removed JavaFX from jdk, you have to add JavaFX as a separate library, which is easy, even adding runtime components so the app launches.
Now the problem I have is when I use template proposal, I'm not getting that description for what it is selected.

Is there a way to add it back? Template proposal list is working fine, I'm just not getting the description anymore for JavaFX.

Example of working fine:
[image: Text]

Example for JavaFX not working (nothing showed about it, like details about what parameters I should use, what the function will return...):
[image: Text]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/bzCMGQ7/not-showing.png))</sub>

Comment: make sure you have the src (or doc) source set in your library/imported modules

Comment: I went to the [official website](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) and downloaded JavaFX Documentation, then for each jar at **Javadoc location** I selected the location for the folder that contains the files **element-list** and **index.html** (as for validation it said **Location is likely valid...***, but even so, it still doesn't appear. At first I tried with **Javadoc in archive**, it was validating the location but when I was closing the windows and opening it back it was saying **Archive can not be found in file system**, that is why I tried with it unzipped.

Comment: attach the src.zip (it's in the download folder of the fx module jars, probably ;) as source location to each module jar

Comment: By adding the source it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following kleopatra advice I managed to make it work again.

If anyone else has the same problem, follow these steps:

- Go to Window / Preferences
- In search field type **User Libraries** and select it
- Expand your librarie name containing the JavaFX jars, then for each javafx.xxx.jar select **Source attachment / Edit...** and add the file **src.zip** located in **lib** subdirectory

Here is an example how I have it:
[image: Text]